# How to use TypeScript's transpile function with JSX/TSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, transpiler, typescript1.6

Let's say I have a TypeScript 1.6 file containing this one single line that contains JSX (TSX):

```
var a = (<div></div>);
```

When I compile this on the command line with TypeScript 1.6 (installed via the ntypescript npm package):

```
ntsc --jsx react test.tsx
```

It produces the expected output:

```
more test.js
var a = (React.createElement("div", null));
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with the TypeScript JS API, I can't get it to work. I run `node` and then run these commands:

```
var ts = require('ntypescript');
src = 'var a = (<div></div>);'
d = []; // for diagnostics
compilerOptions =  {jsx: 'react', module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS};
res =  ts.transpile(src, compilerOptions, 'test.tsx', d);
```

The result I get is:

```
'var a = (<div></div>);\n'
```

Also, `d` is an empty array, so no diagnostic messages (i.e errors) were reported. What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I had to pass in `ts.JsxEmit.React` (which resolves to the number 2) instead of the string `'react'` and then everything works.

So this is the working code:

```
var ts = require('ntypescript');
src = 'var a = (<div></div>);'
d = []; // for diagnostics
compilerOptions =  {jsx: ts.JsxEmit.React, module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS};
res =  ts.transpile(src, compilerOptions, 'test.tsx', d);
```

Output:

```
var a = (React.createElement("div", null));
```

Enjoy!